# AS3- Prevent Dragged Objects from overlapping

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, actionscript

I have an action script 3 minigame where you basically drag and drop. I also have a button that expands when you hover over it. the problem is when it the button is hovered to show a periodic table, the dragged objects overlap.

I want them to stay **below** the periodic table.I already put the periodic table on the topmost layer to no avail. I also tried arranging it (bring to front,etc) [image]

Comment: Where are you adding those dragged objects? Main stage or some sort of container? Because it looks like you're just adding them on top of everything and that's why they cover periodic table. You can also try to re-add table to very top when you hover over it.

Comment: sorry i dont quite understand what you mean. I set the gray and blue squares as the "drop zone",both of them movie clips. How do you re-add the table to the top?

Comment: `addChild()` According to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild()
`The child is added to the front (top) of all other children in this DisplayObjectContainer instance.`

Comment: i have a noob-ish question to ask, do you really need to use import flash.display.Sprite; (or similar) to use Sprite. because i can't get it to work? I do not use external coding in my flash i just code in the Actions layer.

Comment: If you do code on frames, then I don't think you need to `import flash.display.Sprite;`. I just did quick test and the only difference after removing import was no autocompletion

Comment: Please share the code you're using for displaying this periodic table image. If you are simply setting the `visible` property of the image, then the layering shouldn't change.  If you're using `addChild()` it will jump to the top.  You could specify the layer by instead using `parent.addChildAt(child, index)`.  Regardless, if layering isn't the issue, and it's just a matter of interaction, you may simply want to remove all event interaction by setting `mouseEnabled` and `mouseChildren` to false.

Comment: i fixed this already thanks